# Given a proposed characteristic polynomial, how to find an example of a matrix for which this is indeed its characteristic polynomial

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

given that $C(x) = (x+3)(x+2)(x+i)(x-i)$ is a certain characteristic polynomial.
I want to find some **Real numbers** matrix that this $C(x)$ is its characteristic polynomial.
How can I do it?

Comment: Note that the product $(X+\mathbf{i})((X-\mathbf{i})=X^2+1$ has real entries, and therefore so does $C$ (indeed $C(X)=X^4+5X^3+7X^2+5X+6$). It that were not the case there would be no hope of finding a real matrix with $C$ as characteristic polynomial (also it has to be monic, which indeed it is). The rest is standard; search for "companion matrix".

Comment: In general when you want to "build" a matrice that has a certain characteristic polynomial, it can be useful to think about block matrice and the realtion to their ch.polynomial, it will be helpfull to see your line of thought and how you attempt to find the solution to your problem

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can factor any real polynomial into linear terms and quadratic terms. You’ll want to pick one basis vector to correspond to each linear term and two basis vectors for each irreducible quadratic term. Then, take the linear map $M$ such that:

For each linear term $x - r$, you’ll want $M$ to send its associated basis vector $e$ to $re$.

For each irreducible quadratic term $(x - a)^2 + b^2$, you’ll want $M$ to send its associated unit vectors $e$ and $f$ to $ae + bf$ and $-be + af$ respectively.

In this case, the characteristic polynomial of $M$ will be $P$.